# Simple golang IRC bot keeps timing out

Tags: go

I'm tinkering with golang and my first code is a simple IRC bot with the following code:

```
package main

import ("net"
        "log"
        "bufio"
        "fmt"
        "net/textproto"
      )
type Bot struct{
        server string
        port string
        nick string
        user string
        channel string
        pass string
        pread, pwrite chan string
        conn net.Conn
}

func NewBot() *Bot {
        return &Bot{server: "irc.freenode.net",
                    port: "6667",
                    nick: "subsaharan",
                    channel: "#rapidsms", 
                    pass: "",
                    conn: nil,
                    user: "blaze"}
}
func (bot *Bot) Connect() (conn net.Conn, err error){
  conn, err = net.Dial("tcp",bot.server + ":" + bot.port)
  if err != nil{
    log.Fatal("unable to connect to IRC server ", err)
  }
  bot.conn = conn
  log.Printf("Connected to IRC server %s (%s)\n", bot.server, bot.conn.RemoteAddr())
  return bot.conn, nil
}



func main(){
  ircbot := NewBot()
  conn, _ := ircbot.Connect()
  conn.Write([]byte("NICK " + ircbot.nick))
  conn.Write([]byte("JOIN " + ircbot.channel))
  defer conn.Close()

  reader := bufio.NewReader(conn)
  tp := textproto.NewReader( reader )
  for {
        line, err := tp.ReadLine()
        if err != nil {
            break // break loop on errors    
        }
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", line)
    }

}
```

When I run this code I get the following output on the terminal:

```
2012/11/12 13:31:20 Connected to IRC server irc.freenode.net (193.219.128.49:6667)
:sendak.freenode.net NOTICE * :*** Looking up your hostname...
:sendak.freenode.net NOTICE * :*** Checking Ident
:sendak.freenode.net NOTICE * :*** Couldn't look up your hostname
:sendak.freenode.net NOTICE * :*** No Ident response
ERROR :Closing Link: 127.0.0.1 (Connection timed out)
```

Any reason why the connection keeps timing out?

Comment: Thanks for the sample code for a simple go bot.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

All commands sent to an IRC server have a maximum of <strike>255</strike> 512 bytes and must be terminated with a carriage return and linefeed `\r\n`.

```
conn.Write([]byte("NICK " + ircbot.nick + "\r\n"))
conn.Write([]byte("JOIN " + ircbot.channel + "\r\n"))
```

Additionally, freenode expects the `USER` command to be first thing it sees from you.

```
conn.Write([]byte("USER "+ircbot.nick+" 8 * :" + ircbot.nick + "\r\n"))
conn.Write([]byte("NICK " + ircbot.nick + "\r\n"))
conn.Write([]byte("JOIN " + ircbot.channel + "\r\n"))
```

As a side note, you can make your life a little easier by using `fmt.Fprintf` to format and send the data:

```
fmt.Fprintf(conn, "USER %s 8 * :%s\r\n", ircbot.nick, ircbot.nick)
fmt.Fprintf(conn, "NICK %s\r\n", ircbot.nick)
fmt.Fprintf(conn, "JOIN %s\r\n", ircbot.channel)
```

The first parameter of `fmt.Fprintf` must be any type that satisfies the `io.Writer` interface. The `net.Conn` implementations all do this. As such you can pass them into any function which expects an `io.Writer` (or `io.Reader` for that matter) implementation.

Comment: you could also add a helper method like: func (bot *Bot) Cmd(strfmt string, args...interface{}){ fmt.Fprintf(bot.conn, strfmt + "\n", args); }

Comment: Not only freenode expects `USER` to be the first, but it is written in the standard.  Also the standard requires messages to end with `\r\n`, not only `\n`.

Comment: BTW there is a function `PrintfLine` in `net/textproto`, that does exactly what `fmt.Fprintf` does but shorter, better, and correct.

Comment: Oh, sorry.  freenode does *not* expect USER to be the first, it only expects it to be sent generally.

Answer (score 3):

Also, on occasion IRC servers will send a "PING :cookie" message (if for example your connection is idle for too long). You are expected to reply with "PONG :cookie".